# Performing 'find all documents that ...' queries

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm coming from a Postgres background, and I am currently contemplating whether I should use a noSQL database such as mongoDB in my next project. For this I have a few questions

Is it possible to perform queries in noSQL that can fetch all the documents that have some common subdocument/attribute, example "select all users where country = italy"

Also, how is redundancy handled in noSQL? say I have a document that represents a given car model that multiple people can own. Would I then have to insert the same exact data in all these People documents, describing the given car model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do queries with where clause in MongoDB (and other NoSQL engine), if I take your example, you will store the users into a "collection" named "users", and query it more or less the same way.

```
db.users.find( { "country" : "Italy" } );
```

MongoDB has a very rich and powerful query and aggregation engine ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/ ) , I am inviting your to follow the tutorials ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/ )or free online training ( http://university.mongodb.com ), to learn more about it.
To insert the document it is also really easy:

```
db.users.insert( {"first_name" : "John", "last_name" : "Doe", "country" : "USA" }  );
```

that's it!

You talk about redundancy, like in your SQL world it depends a lot of the design. In MongoDB you will organize your document and link between them (linked or embedded documents) based on your business needs. It is hard to give an answer about document design in this context so I will invite you to read some interesting articles:

MongoDB Documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

MongoDB Blog, 6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design (part 1,2,3)
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3

Answer to the question about users and cars, will be "It depends of your application".

If your application is mostly read, and you need most of the data about cars & users, duplication (denormalization), will be a good approach to make the development easy. (and yes you will need more work when you have to update the information...). The blog post and documentation should help you to find your way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do queries in MongoDB on documents that have common subdocument/attribute.
MongoDB encourages embedding(de-normalization) of data as disk space is cheap and embedding docs can result in better query performance.Yes, embedding documents would mean inserting the same data in all People documents in a Car model. But if you want to avoid duplication/de-normalization , then you can go for 'referencing' which is a normalized model which stores data something like this: People collection will contain people docs and Car collection will contain car docs, similar to what we have in rdbms. But the primary/foreign key relationship is not imposed by MongoDB. You will end up doing joins in code and hence query performance will get degraded.

Comment: I see, how would one go about insuring data integrity through denormalization? Say I wanted to change some attribute on a Car document, would I have to visit every single Person document and update the Car subdocument, and would this approach be feasible with a larger dataset?

Comment: This will give you a headstart : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/